# Backslashes are removed unless quoted in command line flags

Tags: string, go, command-line-arguments

I'm using the flag package to interpret flags entered at the command line.

I created a variable using

```
ptrString := flag.String("string", "", "A test string")
flat.Parse()
```

Then when I want to print it,

```
fmt.Println("You entered " + *ptrString)
```

If I enter something like -string=hello! as a command line argument, it prints "hello!"

If I enter something like -string=hello\Bob as a command line argument, it prints "helloBob"

Is there a recommended way to convert or interpret the flag argument to a string that doesn't remove the backslash? (This is being tested on Linux and OS X, if the shell is interfering...)

Comment: Go never sees the `\\`, it's a special character interpreted by the shell.

Comment: @JimB So the only way to pass the argument as-is is to use quotes (-string="hello\Bob")?

Comment: (I wondered if that was the case, but wanted to confirm I wasn't missing something, as I've tested a few variations of reading the flag input and it wasn't showing the backslash)

Comment: yes; or double escape the backslash , or both depending on what you need.

Comment: @JimB If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it... Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters that have special meaning in the shell need to be quoted or escaped. You can find complete list in the shell's man pages (under "Quoting" in `man 1 bash`).

In this case, you can either quote or escape the baskslash

```
-string=hello\\Bob
// or
-string='hello\Bob'
```